# show specified button if any checkbox is checked and hide specified buttons if both is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my snippets, what i want is hide only the button that has class of "save" and the button that has a class of "cancel" if both checkbox is not checked, any ideas, help, suggestions, recommendations?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
    $(".save").show();
    $(".edit").hide();
    $(".cancel").show();
    }else{
    $(".save").hide();
    $(".edit").show();
    $(".cancel").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="edit">edit</button>
<button class="save">save</button>
<button class="cancel">cancel</button>

<input type="checkbox" named="test1" />
<input type="checkbox" named="test2" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $checks = $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var checked = $checks.is(':checked');
    $(".save, .cancel").toggle(checked);
    $(".edit").toggle(!checked);
  });
  $checks.first().change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="edit">edit</button>
<button class="save">save</button>
<button class="cancel">cancel</button>

<input type="checkbox" named="test1" />
<input type="checkbox" named="test2" />
```

Comment: it doesn't hide the button that has a class of "edit" when any of the checkbox is checked and restore it when both checkbox is unchecked? any ideas?